# devenv VS aspnet_compiler

Tags: msbuild, aspnet-compiler, devenv

If I use **aspnet_compiler** to publish an ASP.NET MVC web site, does it do the same tasks that **devenv** would do? Or is it just pre-compiling to minimize the startup delay?

I.E. 
my requirnment is to be able to compile and publish an ASP.NET web site.
in this case, should I use devenv first to build the web site, and then use aspnet_compiler to pre-compile and copy the files over (Publish)?

Or if I just use aspnet_compiler would that also do the building (compiling) of the source and reference projects to relevent dlls?

Your responses are highly appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369250/aspnet-compiler-and-msbuild-exe-question

Answer (score 1):

Lets start from short answer - `aspnet_compiler.exe`  is not related to `ASP.NET MVC`.

MVC projects are compiled either by `devenv.exe` or `msbuild.exe` or whatever else is out there (Roslyn anyone?). But those 2 are provided with VS installation.

`aspnet_compiler` is used [in compilation sense] to compile WSP - web site projects. In WSP each code behind is compiled into separate DLL. But MVC projects compile into single DLL like WAP - web application project.

I doubt you have WSP and MVC, and even if you had one - still, it is better compile using `devenv` because devenv compiles `ashx` files and aspnet_compiler doesn't. This could lead to failures at runtime.

To understand problem better research on

> web site projects vs web application project

Although, I believe in VS15 WSP is gone

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if ther is such thing as aspnet_compiler. Have a look at part of 'Visual C# -> ASP.NET Web Application' project file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

First line is standard C# target. Second, is more interesting as it is ASP.NET specyfic. If you look into its content you will find definition of of **Publish** target and that is probably what you are looking for.

For building and publishing your project you can use (or even just Publish if there are predefined dependencies, I haven't check it)

```
msbuild /t:Build,Publish <project file>
```